# Three.js - Manipulate Width along the X axis

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an object in three js like in the photo. The object it's been exported in json format so i can use it in Three.js. I would like to know how can i manipulate the width between the X axis. Scale is not good for me because in the real object (this here is a simple example) it losses some angles..

Thanks!
[image: This is the object. The material is 1 not 2 and the object is 1 too]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it may concern the problem was that it needs to be 2 objects one the one side and one the other, so i will change the position and not the scale